Python - PPTX: Resize shape to fit text
Powerpoint has the following text options for shapes:

I am able to control the vertical alignment and margins via the following code:
import pptx

from pptx.util import Cm
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE
from pptx.enum.text import MSO_VERTICAL_ANCHOR, MSO_AUTO_SIZE

## Create PowerPoint object
prs = pptx.Presentation("./Template/PPT_Template.pptx")

## Add a slide
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_masters[0].slide_layouts[6])

## Add a rectangular shape at position (5.5, 6.0) (x, y) and dimensions (12.0, 2.0) (w, h)
rec = slide.shapes.add_shape(MSO_SHAPE.RECTANGLE, Cm(5.5), Cm(6.0), Cm(12.0), Cm(2.0))

## Define a text frame for a previously created rectangular shape
txt_frame = rec.text_frame
txt_frame.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."

## Set the options for the text frame
txt_frame.vertical_anchor = MSO_VERTICAL_ANCHOR.TOP
txt_frame.auto_size = MSO_AUTO_SIZE.SHAPE_TO_FIT_TEXT
txt_frame.margin_top = Cm(0.39)
txt_frame.margin_bottom = Cm(0.25)
txt_frame.margin_left = Cm(2.72)
txt_frame.margin_right = Cm(0.25)

## Save presentation
prs.save("./Test.pptx")

Despite setting 'Resize shape to fit text`, whenever I open the produced PowerPoint the shape is not resized. This only happens when I enter an additional space within the PowerPoint presentation.
How do I achieve this using Python?
I am using python-pptx == 0.6.23

It would be easier to help with a minimal reproducible example. Like, I'm sorry to say, but I can't be arsed to spend 15 minutes setting up the txt_frame you're working on to debug this for you =/

@Fynn - Added the minimal reproducible example. But I am also sorry to say that if that would take you 15 minutes to produce you are most likely not capable of answering my question =/

Did you see issue 147? According to this resizing is the responsibility of the rendering-engine like MS-PowerPoint or LibreOffice. Then resizing during design-time in Python might only be achieved programmatically (outside this library).

thanks for the example. considering that hc_dev's comment pretty much amounts to an answer, I think I won't even try
